# How come when I try to unserialize something the result is just empty?

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

For example, I have the string

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:56:"Song → Black Meen : “So Clean (feat. Dullaah Jin)”";s:4:"file";s:98:"http://localhost/peace.worldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/03-So-Clean-feat.-Dullaah-Jin.mp3";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}
```

and I want to unserialize it.

When I pass it in to unserialize(), the result is nothing (so e.g. `print_r(unserialize(/*I put the string here*/))` prints absolutely nothing).

Why might it be happening?

Comment: Btw, I am curious, what are you using that serialization for?

Comment: I'm pulling it out of a database. I didn't make the original app, but I'm using the data it put in the db.

Comment: I would use `JSON` instead. Kinda more reliable as you can parse your data into objects/arrays using other languages than `PHP`.

Comment: That's true, and I totally would, but I didn't make the original app, so I'd have to figure out how to modify all that. I thought I could just unserialize it, but I guess not. The string (with incorrect length fields) is what the app is using, and the app works. I gotta dig more to see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on your notices in error_reporting:

```
PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 204 of 229 bytes in php shell code on line 1
```

Around these offset you have a

```
s:98:"http://localhost/peace.worldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/03-So-Clean-feat.-Dullaah-Jin.mp3"
```

which is indicating that there should be a string of length 98, but the string is only 93 bytes long.

Comment: I fixed my question. Didn't think of it at first. But in my case the numbers match up.

Comment: @trusktr `var_dump(unserialize('a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:4:"blah";s:4:"file";s:25:"http://localhost/blah.mp3";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}'));`
gives `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    ["file"]=>
    string(25) "http://localhost/blah.mp3"
    ["condition"]=>
    string(3) "all"
  }
}
`

Comment: Hmmm.. Mine shows `bool(false)`... I'll just post the actual thing. I think it's harmless.

Comment: @trusktr nope. your length is wrong again: you have `s:98` before the url, but this doesn't match the string length (93).

Comment: Hmmm.... But that's the actual string unmodified from the DB. Does some type of manipulation need to be done to it before I can unserialize it or something? (The app that uses it works fine it seems).

Comment: @trusktr don't know; then collect your whole code where you update the data etc. and put it in an new question. … But when I now have solved your specific question here, please (upvote and) accept it.

Comment: Aha. I found my problem. I had searched/replaced the data based to replace str8wayent.com with localhost, which obviously changes the serialization values, but not the length fields in the DB. I found this nice script to fixed serialization length fields in an sql dump file: https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem causing the serialized strings in the DB to be messed up. I had searched/replaced the data based to replace str8wayent.com with localhost, which obviously changes the serialization values, but not the length fields in the DB.

I found this nice script to fixed serialization length fields in an sql dump file:
[github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization](https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization)